# TypeScript annotate inherited members of derived class

Tags: typescript

Say I have a base class and a number of derived classes. Is there a way to annotate the inherited members without having to re-implement them in the derived classes?

Consider something like this:

```
class BaseModel {
  collection: Collection;

  constructor(collectionName: string) {
    this.collection = connectToCollection(collectionName);
  }

  create(data: {}) { // <- I would like to annotate 'data' in the derived classes
    this.collection.insert(data);
  }
}

class ModelA extends BaseModel {
  constructor(collectionName: string) {
    super(collectionName);
  }
}

class ModelB extends BaseModel {
  constructor(collectionName: string) {
    super(collectionName);
  }
}
```

The argument for the `create` member is different for ModelA and ModelB, so I would like to annotate them separately.

I guess I can re-implement them like this:

```
class ModelA extends BaseModel {
  constructor(collectionName: string) {
    super(collectionName);
  }

  create(data: ArgsForModelA) {
    this.super.create(data);
  }
}

class ModelB extends BaseModel {
  constructor(collectionName: string) {
    super(collectionName);
  }

  create(data: ArgsForModelB) {
    this.super.create(data);
  }
}
```

But it just does not feel right, so I am curious to if it's possible to annotate the inherited members without re-implementing each one of them in all the derived classes (phew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics for this.

```
class BaseModel<T> {

  collection: Collection;

  constructor(collectionName: string) {
    this.collection = connectToCollection(collectionName);
  }

  create(data: T) {
    this.collection.insert(data);
  }
}

class ModelA extends BaseModel<ArgsForModelA> {
  constructor(collectionName: string) {
    super(collectionName);
  }
}

class ModelB extends BaseModel<ArgsForModelB> {
  constructor(collectionName: string) {
    super(collectionName);
  }
}
```